# Вывести количество курсов на экран Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

Делаю небольшое англуляр прилождение ,которое отображает количество курсов в таблице, по чекбоксу пользователь выбирает прошел ли он тот или иной курс. Я хочу вывести статистику по количество пройденных курсов, но не могу сообразить как.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="courseListApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Модель

 var model = {
            user: "User1",
            courses: [{ name: "HTML, CSS", passed: true },
                { name: "JavaScript Essential", passed: true },
                { name: "JavaScript Advanced", passed: true },
                { name: "HTML5 &amp; CSS3", passed: false },
                { name: "AngularJS", passed: false }]
        };

        // Модуль

        var courseListApp = angular.module("courseListApp", []);

        // Контроллер

        courseListApp.controller("CourseListCtrl", function ($scope) {

            $scope.data = model;


            // Обработчик нажатия по кнопке
            $scope.addNewCourse = function () {

                $scope.data.courses.push({
                    name: $scope.courseName,
                    passed: "No"
                });

                $scope.courseName = "";
            }
            $scope.setStyle = function(passed){
                return passed ? "color:green": "color:red";
            }
            $scope.showText = function(passed){
                return passed ? "Да": "Нет";
            }


        });
    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="CourseListCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>
                    Планировщик курсов.
                </h1>
                <h3>Пользователь: {{data.user}}. Количество курсов - {{data.courses.length}}</h3>
<p>Пройдено {{}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="courseName" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewCourse()">Добавить</button>
                </span>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Курс</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Пройден</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="course in data.courses">
                        <td>{{course.name}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="course.passed"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <span style ="{{setStyle(course.passed)}}">
                                {{showText(course.passed)}}

                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Хочу вывести все вот сюда   `<p>Пройдено {{}}</p>` Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, используя фильтр так:
`<p>Пройдено {{(data.courses | filter: {passed: true}).length}}</p>`

Также Вам стоит изучить встроенные возможности шаблонизатора Ангуляр, поскольку логика отображения данных должна быть в шаблоне, а не в контроллере.

Например это:
`<span style ="{{setStyle(course.passed)}}">`

заменить на: 
`<span ng-style="{color: course.passed ? 'green' : 'red'}">` убрав функцию из контроллера.

Или `{{showText(course.passed)}}`
 заменив на `{{course.passed ? "Да": "Нет"}}`